# PHP Issue - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, yii, namespaces

Does anyone know if there's a good instruction guide for implementing the new php standards for CI2 or CI3?
Running a simple VPS with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server - CI3 for the secure section CI2 for the general website and registration processes. 
After building on Yii and Laravel the past two months it came to my attention that certain parts in CI classes dont use the same notation.
example: // importing a constant (PHP 5.6+)
use const My\Full\CONSTANT;

If there is a bright minded developer out there who can give me a head start in finding more about this I would be grateful.

Kind regards

Comment: Their [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/) specifies the coding standards.

Comment: you can find guide [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html) and more [here](https://www.php-fig.org/psr)

Comment: Why did you switch from Laravel to CI? Just recently I jumped from Kohana (codeigniter derivative that i really loved compared to codeigniter) to Laravel and I actually loved that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the use of an automated standards check, using a tool like [CodeSniffer](http://www.squizlabs.com/php-codesniffer).

Codesniffer is flexible enough to create sniffs for your own standard. I have not used CI for a long while, but there are [older versions of sniffs for codeigniter](https://github.com/thomas-ernest/CodeIgniter-for-PHP_CodeSniffer). You could seek out later versions.

https://github.com/thomas-ernest/CodeIgniter-for-PHP_CodeSniffer

Comment: Nice input - this got me going!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I work different projects and this specific job was requested to be completed in codeigniter. Therefore the switch and the discovery that the 5.6 calls, classes and references are not being used. I will look into the documents deeper.